# Where to store "loading" and "loadError" objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

My state shape looks like this:

```
export default {
    app: {
        selectedThing: {},
        loading: false,
        loadError: null
    },
    search: {
        type: null,
        text: ''
    },
    things: {
        byId: {

        },
        allIds: []
    },
}
```

As recommended by the Redux docs, I'm storing my models `byId` and `allIds` for order. However, when I fetch a `thing` from the server, I want to be able to set `loading` and `loadError` so that the UI can display some sort of message. I'm using `combineReducers`

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import things from './things'
import search from './search'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    things,
    search
})

export default rootReducer
```

... which only updates a slice of the state.

```
// ./things.js
import { LOAD_THINGS_SUCCESS } from '../actions/actionTypes'
import initialState from './initialState'

export default function things(state = initialState.things, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case LOAD_THINGS_SUCCESS:
            console.log(action.things)
            return {
                ...state,
                byId: action.things.forEach(thing => {
                    state[thing.id] = thing
                }),
                allIds: action.things.map(thing => {
                    return thing.id
                })
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

I dispatch `LOADING` and `LOAD_ERROR` actions in my API calls, and then `LOAD_THINGS_SUCCESS` which are consumed by individual reducers. However, in order to set `app.loading` to `true`, each individual reducer somehow needs access to the `app` slice. One way to do this would be to dispatch `loadSuccess()` which is consumed by `reducers/app.js` and then `loadThingsSuccess()` which is consumed by `reducers/thing.js`. However, this seems hacky and not DRY. Should I  be maintaining the "loading" status of each `state.things` and `state.otherThings` and have actions like `LOADING_THINGS` and `LOADING_THINGS_ERROR` or should they be kept in `state.app` - if so how should I modify them?

Thanks!

Comment: I don' think it having `LOADING_START`, `LOADING_ERROR` and `LOADING_DONE` actions is overly verbose or "hacky" - if loading is an application context action, then by all means. If, however, loading is local to a component, then perhaps you should just store that information within the component state.

Comment: @TylerSebastian wouldn't maintaining component state violate "keep your state as flat as possible" ? It seems as though the docs recommend keeping domain specific data away from UI and app state related properties.

Comment: I don't disagree with you... however, in my opinion, if the loading action is only relevant to the local component, then why should it be accessible to the rest of the app? If necessary, you can lift the state up a couple levels if other aspects of your app that are closely related to the component rely on knowing the loading state.